# Conditional workflow email automatically sent when a single field changes

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-email, conditional

I have a list (CRM) and there is a field where a representative is assigned. The rep gets an email when the field is filled in for the first time. **How do I make a workflow so that if the rep is changed, the new rep gets an email?**

NOTE: We don't want an email sent to the intake rep each time any of the other fields are changed, which is currently what is happening when selecting "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed."

Answer (score 0):

You're working in a 2013 Workflow?
In your list, create a field named "EmailSent", of type Yes/No. Set the default to "No"
In your workflow, create a variable of type character. Assign this with your field info. Check if this field aren't blank and if EmailSent is set to "No". In this case, send the email and set the "EmailSent" field to "Yes".